# Homotopy groups of path space satisfying $\pi_k(\Omega_{p,q})=\pi_{k+1}(X)$.

Tags: homotopy-theory

> The space of all continuous paths $\omega:[0,1]\to X$ from $p$ to $q$ in the compact open topology will be denoted by $\Omega_{p,q}$. The homotopy group $\pi_{k}(X,x_0)$ is defined by $[(S^k,z_0),(X,x_0)]$. Prove that $\pi_k(\Omega_{p,q})=\pi_{k+1}(X)$.

**My attempt**

I thought that we need to treat $f_t:S^k\to \Omega_{p,q}$ as a map $\tilde{f_t}:S^{k+1}\to X$ where $f_t(z_0)\equiv \omega_0$ will imply that $\tilde{f_t}(\tilde{z_0})\equiv x_0$ for some $\tilde{z_0}\in S^{k+1}$. In the case that $p=q$ I can construct the relation naturally, but I got stuck on the case $p\ne q$. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the basepoint in $\Omega_{p,q}$ that you are using to define homotopy groups when $p\neq q$?

Comment: @Tyrone The basepoint is some continuous path $\omega:[0,1]\to X$ from $p$ to $q$, which is also a point in $\Omega_{p,q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $p,q$ lie in different path components of $X$, then $\Omega_{p,q}X$ is empty while $\Omega_{p,p}X$ contains at least the constant path. I'll assume below that $X$ is path-connected for simplicity.

Suppose given three points $p,q,r\in X$. Choose a path $l:I\rightarrow X$ such that $l(0)=q$ and $l(1)=r$. Then the map
$$\theta_l:\Omega_{p,q}X\rightarrow \Omega_{p,r}X,\qquad k\mapsto k+l$$
is a homotopy equivalence. The homotopy inverse is supplied by
$$\theta_{-l}:\Omega_{p,r}X\rightarrow\Omega_{p,q}X,\qquad k'\mapsto k'-l.$$
To finish we take $r=p$ and use what you have already obtained in the special case $p=q$. I'll leave the details to you. Let me know if you get stuck.

Note that if you don't care about basepoints, then the maps above can be made to respect basepoints simply by re-choosing basepoints. The required homotopies will not in general preserve these basepoints unless some reasonable assumptions are made about $X$. However, a basepoint preserving map which is a free homotopy equivalence will induce isomorphisms on all homotopy groups.